Bootable Ubuntu live USB as regular installation without installer
I'd like to create a bootable Ubuntu installation on a USB flash drive that I can bring between computers and keep the configuration on it.
Flashing the ISO onto the USB and creating a persistent storage volume via Rufus results in the working environment being reset every time I start from the USB, as I'm assuming it mounts some kind of compressed filesystem every time it starts.
What is the best way to create a regular Ubuntu installation on the USB, that I can bring between computers?
Thanks
Daniel

This question is similar to: How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

'...Flashing the ISO onto the USB and creating a persistent storage volume via Rufus results in the working environment being reset every time...' no it doesn't. I have just created a lubuntu one. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-persistent-live-usb/

Why not a full install on flash drive. I have done that for years. But now find an external SSD so much faster that I only have one or two installs on flash drives as tests. And now two SSDs. Installs now are UEFI. But to use SSD on old BIOS system, I was able to add a BIOS boot stanza on old 2006 laptop's HDD to boot install on SSD. SSD regularly used with newish UEFI only laptop & bit older desktop.
